# 'as' as a pronoun or conjunction

Tags: conjunctions, pronouns, as

In this passage from Bertrand Russell's *The History of Western Philosophy*:

> Various forces have put an end to this state of affairs. First, democracy, **as** embodied in the French Revolution and its aftermaths. The cultured gentlemen, **as** after the age of Pericles, had to defend their privileges against the populace, and in the process ceased to be either gentlemen or cultured.

Are these two instances of *as* pronouns or conjunctions?

Comment: *As* is never a pronoun; I think you probably mean *preposition*. If so, the answer depends on what school of analysis you follow. The *Cambridge Grammar of the English Language*, for instance, has 'recategorized' most of what traditional grammar called *subordinating conjunctions* as *prepositions*.

Comment: By the way, this paragraph is in some respects non-Standard. It's easy enough to understand, but it wouldn't be acceptable in most academic writing.

Comment: Thanks, Stoney, I usually use MW as my reference. And they state 'as' an [pronoun](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/as). I'm confused. I took this paragraph from Russell's book 'The History of Western Philosophy'. His writing is indeed non-Standard.

Comment: MW is grasping at straws. *As* may be used in places where it can be paraphrased with a nominal, but it is not used *as* a nominal: it's a comparative operator. And Russell is guilty of some very slovenly proofreading there; but in context I now see why *cultured gentlemen* bears the definite article.

Comment: A pronoun stands for a noun. What noun should "as" replace? In traditional grammar "as"  is a conjunction, i.e. it can introduce a clause. It can be a temporal/causal/comparative conjunction.  And "as" can be a kind of preposition when followed by a noun as in as friend, as guest, as engineer.

Comment: @StoneyB The paragraph was written by a winner of the Nobel prize for literature, a Fellow of the Royal Society and a professor of philosopy at Trinity College. His writing almost *defines" what is acceptable for academic writing!

Comment: @JamesKilfiger I never said he wasn't a good writer; but this passage looks to me like dictated copy which was revised only in haste, if at all.

Comment: t is from the History of Western Philosophy. I have the text here and the OP has quoted it correctly. Russell's writing is superb, though challenging for a learner. It is a model of academic writing, and completely standard English. This really belongs in chat...

Comment: The first “as” is a pronoun and subject of the sentence. It’s antecedent is “democracy.” "democracy" is an appositive in this sentence.  Another example, “First, chocolate cookies, they are my favorite snack.” NOTE: an appositive may come **before** the word it identifies/explains.|| **As**. *pron*. See definition number 3. http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/as | AND | https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=as&submit.x=0&submit.y=0

Comment: The second “as” is again a pronoun referring to “gentlemen” and is used as an *appositive* in the appositive phrase explaining/identifying gentlemen: “as after the age of Pericles.” “3j. An *appositive* is noun or pronoun that follows another noun or pronoun to identify or explain it. 3k. An *appositive phrase* is made up of the appositive and its modifiers.” —John E. Warriner. Warriner’s English Grammar and Composition. Third Course. Liberty Edition. Orlando, Florida: Harcourt, Brace, and Jovanovich. 1986. 113.

Comment: The first **as** in "democracy, as..." could be paraphrased "in the manner".  The second **as**, in "gentlemen, as..." is a relative and could be paraphrased "who": "gentlemen ... as had to defend", analogous to the citation from Shakespeare M-W gives: *that kind of fruit as maids call medlars*  That's just Russell talking  rude mechanical.

Answer (score 1):

They're both adverbs. [The MW Learner's Dictionary says that the **as** can be used in formal registers to introduce examples](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/as).

It's more common to introduce an example with the phrase **such as**, rather than with **as** all by itself. That may be why it's not so easy to recognize the usage here.

By the by, the MW Learner's Dictionary lists **as** as an adverb, a conjunction, and a preposition, but not as a pronoun.

Answer (score 0):

The first one is a conjunction - it combines a word (democracy) with a separate phrase which describes them. I think 'as' is never used as a pronoun; it is often used as<sup>*</sup> a preposition.

The second one looks like a conjunction as<sup>*</sup> well, but the sentence sounds a bit strange to me.

<sup>*</sup> (Bonus questions): what roles do 'as' play here?

Comment: Thanks. The first 'as', I think, plays as an preposition, the second an adverb.

Comment: @MichaelSong It's definitely not a preposition. It's interchangeable with *when* here, so it's an adverb.