# Is ‘be’ without a complement grammatical?

Tags: usage

The following quotation (with a link to the source) is from a title to an Amazon product review.

> [Not selling the product **as** they claim it to be](https://www.amazon.com/gp/customer-reviews/R37AQSQ07ABMIV/ref=cm_cr_arp_d_rvw_ttl?ie=UTF8&ASIN=B0045RLTPE).

I can understand the meaning, but not figure out the syntactic structure.

I have found the same construction used in the Cambridge Dictionary:

> [To accept something as it appears to be.](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/take-at-face-value?q=take%20something%20at%20face%20value)

Seemingly, 'selling' and 'to accept' are non-finite phrases. The two sentences have very similar structure, except that 'the product' is different from something,and I am not sure whether this is the point .

According to my information, following the verb 'be' there often is a complement, but here the verb ends the sentence. Is there something omitted? Or is there another process at work of which I am unaware?

Comment: I'm closing this question because it's bad English, and not from a reliable source (a random Amazon reviewer).

Comment: @gotube Ok,thanks.

Comment: @gotube Hi, I have come across the same structure ['accept something as it appears to be'](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/take-at-face-value?q=take+something+at+face+value). After google,I have found some other similar sentences,i.e. 'accept things as they are'.  So, are these also bad usages?

Comment: No, those usages are correct and natural. The one you gave has several problems with it and isn't worth correcting. It's certainly not worth learning from.

Comment: That example may be awkward, but there's nothing wrong with it grammatically. I forget the grammatical name of the process, but the complement of the verb is brought to the front - a similar thing happens in relative clauses (eg "the man who he appeared to be" and some Wh-questions (eg "What did you think it was?")

Comment: @Colin Fine Why is 'selling the product...' awkward, not 'accept something as it appears to be'.

Comment: @gotube Could you point out the several problems? Very very thanks.

Comment: @Mr.Wang Sorry. Finding errors isn't something we do on this site. The wording is so awkward that I can't even figure out how to rephrase it properly.

Comment: @gotube Got it. Thanks anyway.

Comment: The sentence may be clumsy, but it's an example of day-to-day English. And the OP is asking primarily about how a sentence can end with a bare 'to be' when they expect a complement to be required, which is a good question. To close with the claim the question 'does not appear to be about learning the English language' makes no sense to me. I think this question should be re-opened

Comment: Have a look at these (from the hundreds of questions about "as"): https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/196007/as-as-it-gets-vs-as-as-can-be https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/230745/as-you-did-as-did-you https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/197700/as-as-a-relative-pronoun https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/30281/as-suggested-as-is-suggested-as-it-is-suggested https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/59728/as-as-a-pronoun-or-conjunction https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/210798/the-earth-as-seen-from-the-moon-why-as

Comment: @StuartF I can understand these 'as' that you list. But, they are not the same as I post above.

Comment: @StuartF  "To accept such something as appears to be [???]." should be a standard sentence. Here 'as' functions as a pronoun or conjunction with omitting the subject. And the question is what should follow 'be'?